# prove that $\lim \limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} n \sum \limits_{j=1}^{n} \frac{cos(\frac{n}{j}) f(\frac{n}{j})}{j^2}$ exists and final.

Tags: calculus, limits, summation

$f$ is monotonically decreasing function such that $\lim \limits_{x \rightarrow\infty} f(x) =0$, prove that the following limit exists and final .

$$\lim \limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} n \sum \limits_{j=1}^{n} \frac{cos(\frac{n}{j}) f(\frac{n}{j})}{j^2}$$

in any case i think i need to prove first the sum converges .... and than try moving the limit inside or change the order of summation .... or move the $n$ inside the sum and then try to prove convergence . 
but cant think of a way to prove the sum converges i think i need to use Abel's or Dirichlet's convergence tests for function series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything's easier with Riemann sums:
$$n\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{\cos\left(\frac{n}{j}\right)f\left(\frac{n}{j}\right)}{j^2}\approx \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{x^2}\,dx = \int_{1}^{+\infty}f(x)\cos x\,dx$$
and the last integral exists by Dirichlet's criterion, since $\cos x$ has a bounded primitive while $f(x)$ is a decreasing function such that $\lim_{x\to +\infty} f(x)=0.$

Comment: thanks .... wow it's short and nice ..... i was expecting something long and ugly :D